# How to upload data to Jupyter Hub from hosting Server?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I setup Jupyter Hub on my server by following [this guide](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/custom-server.html). I have my Dataset on that server and I want to either upload to or make visible to the JupyterHub running on the http://ip-of-my-server. The data uploading guide is about uploading the data from the JupyterHub GUI, **but want it done from the back-end.**

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The root directory of jupyterhub is present on the hosting server at `/home/jupyter-adminusername`, where adminusername is the one you used while creating the jupyterhub instance as mentioned [here](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/custom-server.html#step-1-installing-the-littlest-jupyterhub). You can add files in this directory to make them visible in the jupyter browser window.